# How can I merge two array data in react native?

Tags: reactjs, native

I want fetch 2 data and push array, then merge these two data, who can help me?

My first data example;

```
{

  "experts": [
    {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "XXXXX",
        "integration_id": "1",
    },
    {
        "id": 243,
        "name": "YYYY",
        "integration_id": "2",

    },
  ] 
}
```

My Second data example https://xxx/api/?staff={integration_id}

```
{
  "uzmanlar": [
    {
      "id": "1",
      "ad_soyad": "xxx",
      "pic": "117-k-xxx.jpg",
    }
  ],
}
```

I want foreach first data array to second data merge. I want print picture screen.

Answer (score 0):

```
 const arr1 = res.exprts;
const arr2 = res.uzmanlar;
Array.prototype.push.apply(arr1, arr2);
console.log(arr1) // final merge result would be in arr1
```

you can try this...

Comment: I'll try, but can you explain the code a little more? Because in order to get the second yield, I need to return the ids in the first data in my second fetch

Comment: this code is quite self-explanatory, but I'd try to simplify this, in arr1 we are simply extracting the exprts from the response and the same goes for arr2
if you wanna use the ids of arr1 then you do arr1[0].id , arr[1].id to access the ids

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this using the [`...` Spread Syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax):

```
const array = [...obj1["experts"], ...obj1["uzmanlar"]]
```

This creates a new array including all elements of the first and second array.